# Is a TP5100 module redundant with "protected button top" 18650 cells?

Tags: lithium-ion, safety, charging, 18650, tp5100

I am going to use a [TP5100 module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/461036/17697) in a device to manage two 18650 cells in a 2S configuration.

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to use "protected button top" batteries in this circuit ([example](https://www.18650batterystore.com/products/samsung-30q-protected-pcb?variant=37145691553943)) as opposed to their non-protected equivalents ([example](https://www.18650batterystore.com/products/samsung-30q?variant=37119891374231))?

Comment: the title looks unfinished

Comment: @jsotola, thanks, finished it!

Answer (score 2):

The protected 18650 batteries protect themselves but will slowly go out of balance.

Instead, the unprotected 18650 cells, plus a 2S BMS, will be protected and kept in balance, so that's a better solution.